# How do I make a Python script along with its modules self-contained?

Tags: python

programming novice here with a development management question.

I'm writing a very simple Python script in Windows 7 that will be copied into a directory of Excel files sort it all by filename, exclude the scriptfile in the directory, and process them in order.

I've installed both Python 2.7 and 3.4 on my system which resides in C:\Python27 and C:\Python34 respectively.

I've written the sorting part which I'm happy with, but I've had to install the natsort module, which was supposed to be compatible only with 2.7, but was automatically installed by pip into my C:\Python34... directories instead... I must run the script as "C:\Python34\python tvcrunch.py" without getting an ImportError: No module named natsort.

Now I need to install the xlrd and xlwt packages for processing my Excel files, and they installed into C:\Python27... directories despite being compatible with Python 3.2+.

I think by now you all understand the conundrum I'm in. I would like this script to be portable enough so I can drop it onto any computer and have it run without needing to reinstall all these modules and packages. How do I do that? Script below:

```
import os
from os import listdir
import natsort

somedir = r'.'
fileList = []

def list_files(path):
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, item)):
            if item != r'tvcrunch.py':
                fileList.append(item)
    return fileList

list_files(somedir)
natsort.natsorted(fileList, key=lambda y: y.lower())
print(fileList)
```

Comment: Bundle your python install with it, this is what's typically done, and there's really no easier way.

Comment: It sounds like you mostly just need to get more comfortable installing Python packages. Installing pip-enabled modules is very easy once you get the hang of it. You need to make sure that you're running the *right* pip, though. If you run your Python 2.7 pip, it'll install to your Python 2.7 installation.

Comment: There are a variety of different third-party solutions that handle this in different ways—from `cx_Freeze` to `pyInstaller` and `py2exe` to portable `virtualenv`s, all the way up to deploying entire virtual machines. Unfortunately, StackOverflow's Q&A format makes this a bad place to get a recommendation for which solution or tool will work best (especially since "best" depends on a whole lot of information about your use case that someone is probably going to have to get out of you via discussion).

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking to building a single native windows executable check

http://www.py2exe.org/

Tutorial link: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

Support for Python 3.x https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/0.9.2.0

"
py2exe is a Python extension which converts Python scripts into executable Windows programs, able to run without requiring a Python installation.Spice
"

Comment: Last time I checked, Python 3.x support was still "coming soon", and there hadn't been a new release since last decade. When I look at the [news](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/News) page on the linked website, it still ends in 2008.

Comment: Right. I didn't notice the required Python version in your question. However it says here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py2exe/0.9.2.0 that Python 3 is supported.